# How to understand which test failed in ink!

Tags: ink

I've been testing my ink! contract and one of the tests failed.
The test that failed:

```
#[ink::test]
fn get_bids_made_works() {
    let bid = 100u128;
    let mut bag = Moneybag::new(bid);
    let accounts = default_accounts::<DefaultEnvironment>();
    let bob: AccountId = accounts.bob;
    set_caller::<DefaultEnvironment>(bob);
    bag.add_bid(bid).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(bag.get_bids_made(), 3);       
}
```

The Error message:

```
 Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.76s
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/moneybag-1ffd8ca9ab27f17f)
error: test failed, to rerun pass '--lib'
ERROR: `"/home/creestl/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo" "test" ""` failed with exit code: Some(101)
```

From the error message it is *not* clear which test function that was. But to me it was just obvious that it was the `get_bids_made_works` that I've provided above. But what if it was not so obvious? And what if instead of 6 tests I had 50?
I see that in the error message there is a `"test" ""` part. And I suppose that it should include the name of the test function, but it does not. Should I use some macro to define test's name? e.g.:

```
#[ink::test]
#[ink::test_name("NiceTest")]
. 
.
.
```

How do I distinguish one failed test from another?

Comment: Please add more details and a snippet of this test. [how to ask a good question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is something to review too ;) As is, this isn't a good question

Comment: I've added some code and details. Pls, take a look.

Comment: Can you try using `cargo +nightly test` instead of `cargo +nightly contract test` and post the output here? The latter doesn't provide very helpful output (see https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/421).

Comment: Oh wow, it really gives a much more detailed output. I was using `cargo +nightly contract test` just because of [this line](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract#:~:text=the%20target/%20directory.-,cargo%20contract%20test,-Runs%20test%20suites). But your advise solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cargo +nightly test` instead of `cargo +nightly contract test`